# Flask-sqlalchemy pagination seems to hide data

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a weird situation using pagination on msearch (https://github.com/honmaple/flask-msearch):

```
results = Project.query.msearch(f"{search_query}").paginate(per_page = 20)
```

and in my template:

```
{% for result in results.item %}
  {{ result.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now without pagination, the result from msearch displays just fine, but pagination seems to get rid of the data. How is this possible? If anyone has a solution to this problem or an alternative pagination method in flask I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `{% for result in results.item %}` should be `{% for result in results.items %}`? http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.Pagination.items

Comment: Yep, that works! Thanks, I feel dumb now haha